# subscript operator overload returning pointer and assigning value to it

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, reference

I got a situation where I have a `class` `B` having a protected `array` of `A*`. I have an another function `A* func()` which returns pointers to `A` objects stored in some other container. (for example `std::map<int,A*>` or `A* arr[]`).

For example the following implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    A(int _x): x(_x){};
    int x;
};
class B{
public:
    B() {
        this->arr[0] = new A(1);
        this->arr[1] = new A(2);
    }
    // use idx to index in to the internal array and return A*
    A*& operator[](int idx); // return reference to pointer to avoid not a lvalue error
private:
    // class B has this private array of A*
    A* arr[2];
};

A*& B::operator[](int idx) {
    return this->arr[idx]; // 0<=idx<=1
}



A* arr[2];
A* func(int x) {
    return arr[x]; // 0<=idx<=1
}

int main() {
    arr[0] = new A(12);
    arr[1] = new A(14);

    B b;

    b[1] = func(1); // assign a new value

    cout << b[1]->x << endl; // prints 14
}
// memory leaks of this program can be removed using `std::shared_ptr<A>` in the place of `A*`.
```

In this example, `operator[]()` returns a reference to a pointer, because returning pointer becomes `rvalue` and I will not be able to assign value to it (i.e. `b[1] = func(1)`).

My question is, is this `reference to pointer returning` recommended (other ways to achieve this )? or is this perfectly fine with raw pointers as well as with `shared_ptr`?

Thank You!

Comment: As alternative you have still setter.

Comment: Using raw pointers in your application code is always fraught with problems. Unless there are strong reasons to avoid use of smart pointers, use smart pointers.

Comment: @Jarod42 you mean this ? `b.setValue(idx, func(1))` ?

Comment: Yeah, I mean this.

Comment: If your class models a collection of pointers, then I don't see anything wrong with `operator[]` returning a reference to a pointer. More generally, a class that models a collection of elements of type `T` may quite reasonably provide an `operator[]` overload returning `T&`; the fact that `T` may happen to be a pointer type makes no difference. For instance, `std::vector<int*>::operator[]` would in fact return `int*&`